# Flip a coin 6 times. 4 heads are guaranteed, what is the probability of 4 consecutive heads

Tags: probability

No idea how to solve this one...
Flip a coin 6 times....
Events:

`A = “the coin comes up heads at least four times”`

`B = “there are at least four consecutive heads”.`

What is Pr(B|A)? Meaning what is the probability of there being 4 consecutive heads given that the coin comes up heads at least 4 times...

I have found the Pr(A) is 34.38% and Pr(B) is 12.5%

Comment: How did you get your answers and why do you doubt them?

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that you computed your probabilities of $\Pr[A]$ and $\Pr[B]$ correctly.  Then, by Bayes theorem, $$\Pr[B \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[A \mid B]\Pr[B]}{\Pr[A]}.$$  But $$\Pr[A \mid B] = 1,$$ because $B$ is a subset of $A$:  if $B$ occurred, then $A$ is also guaranteed to have occurred.  So the desired probability is $$\Pr[B \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[B]}{\Pr[A]}.$$

That said, you need to check that you did in fact compute those probabilities correctly.  For $A$, the ideal choice is to use the binomial distribution:  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[A] &= \sum_{k=4}^6 \binom{6}{k} p^k (1-p)^{6-k} \\ &= 15p^4 (1-p)^2 + 6 p^5 (1-p) + p^6, \end{align*}$$ where $p$ is the individual probability of obtaining heads on a single coin flip.  $\Pr[B]$ is calculated by direct enumeration:  write out all the outcomes for which there are at least four consecutive heads:  $$\begin{align*}  & (H,H,H,H,T,T) \\ & (H,H,H,H,T,H) \\ & (T,H,H,H,H,T) \\ & (H,T,H,H,H,H) \\ &(T,T,H,H,H,H) \\ &(H,H,H,H,H,T) \\ & (T,H,H,H,H,H) \\ & (H,H,H,H,H,H). \end{align*}$$  So the total probability is $$3p^4 (1-p)^2 + 4p^5 (1-p) + p^6,$$ again for the general case where the probability of heads is $p$.  So the desired conditional probability is (after some simplification)  $$\Pr[B \mid A] = \frac{3-2p}{15-24p+10p^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an unbiased coin:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P(A) & = \dfrac 1 {2^6}\left(\dbinom{6}{4}+\dbinom{6}{5}+\dbinom{6}{6}\right)
 & \text{from ways to select 4, 5, or 6 heads}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{11}{32}
\\[2ex]
P(B) & =\dfrac 1{2^6} \left(3 + 2+1 + 2 \right)
& \text{from ways to select a block of heads and 2, 1, or 0 tails;}
\\[0ex] && \text{including a 4heads-tail-head and head-tail-4heads}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{4}{32}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(B\mid A) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A)}
& \text{by definition of conditional probability}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(A)} & \text{since } B\subset A
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{4}{11}
\end{array}$

Comment: @heropup Ah, yes, of course.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to confirm your value of $P(B)$:

Since the coin is tossed only six times, to have four heads in a row the third and fourth
tosses must be heads. So we have $16$ possible events of the form

$$ (X_1, X_2, H, H, X_5, X_6) $$

where the $X_i$ could be either $H$ or $T$.
Of these $16$ events, all except the following have four heads in a row:

$$\begin{align}
(X_1, T, H, H, T, X_6) & \quad (4\ \mbox{ways}),\\
(T, H, H, H, T, X_6) & \quad (2\ \mbox{ways}),\\
(X_1, T, H, H, H, T) & \quad (2\ \mbox{ways}).
\end{align}$$

Those cases include $8$ of the possible events,
so the remaining $8$ out of $16$ events all have four heads in a row.
These are $8$ of a total of $64$ equally probable ways for the six tosses to occur,
so the probability is
$$P(B) = \frac{8}{64} = \frac18.$$